# Got java.nio.file.InvalidPathException:Illegal char <:> at index 7 when formatting javascript file using closure compiler

Tags: java, processbuilder, google-closure-compiler

I am using google closure compiler to format a number of javascript files in my web project. Thus I am writting a Java application to traverse all the js files under root directory. For testing purpose I just give a try on a single javascript file as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        JSBeautifier js = new JSBeautifier();
        js.beautify("'C:/CodeScanner/src/test/resources/testJS.js'");
    }

    public void beautify(String filePath) {
        String srcFileArg = "--js " + filePath;

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar" , "compiler.jar", srcFileArg).inheritIO();

        try {
            Process p  = pb.start();
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while(br.readLine() != null){
                System.out.println(br.readLine());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

However, when it is executed it gives the exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 7: --js 'C:/CodeScanner/src/test/resources/testJS.js'
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
    at com.google.javascript.jscomp.CommandLineRunner.findJsFiles(CommandLineRunner.java:1753)
    at com.google.javascript.jscomp.CommandLineRunner.findJsFiles(CommandLineRunner.java:1730)
    at com.google.javascript.jscomp.CommandLineRunner$Flags.getJsFiles(CommandLineRunner.java:928)
    at com.google.javascript.jscomp.CommandLineRunner.initConfigFromFlags(CommandLineRunner.java:1325)
    at com.google.javascript.jscomp.CommandLineRunner.<init>(CommandLineRunner.java:1176)
    at com.google.javascript.jscomp.CommandLineRunner.main(CommandLineRunner.java:1834)
```

While in command line this action (java -jar compiler.jar --js 'C:/CodeScanner/src/test/resources/testJS.js') can be successfully performed.

Can anyone please give a hand ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like ProcessBuilder is trying to execute:

```
java "-jar" "compiler.jar" "--js 'C:/CodeScanner/src/test/resources/testJS.js'"
```

Which is causing the js compiler to see:

```
argv[0] = "--js 'C:/CodeScanner/src/test/resources/testJS.js'"
```

instead of:

```
argv[0] = "--js"
argv[1] = "'C:/CodeScanner/src/test/resources/testJS.js'"
```

To correct this, I would try changing:

```
String srcFileArg = "--js " + filePath;
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar" , "compiler.jar", srcFileArg).inheritIO();
```

into

```
String srcFileArg = filePath;
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar" , "compiler.jar", "--js", srcFileArg).inheritIO();
```

Comment: Thx. the explanation is lucid,

Comment: do you have any idea if "--formatting" is not applicable for the above approach? I try adding --formatting pretty_print but it doesn't take any effect. The purpose of doing so is I just want to remove the empty lines and comments from my js files but keep the line breaks.

Comment: It should be. Try `--formatting="PRETTY_PRINT"` as a single argument.